# Reaction of phosphorous acid (H3PO3) and potassium hydroxide (KOH)

Tags: acid-base

For the reaction of phosphorous acid ($\ce{H3PO3}$) and potassium
hydroxide ($\ce{KOH}$), write (a) the balanced molecular equation
and (b) the net ionic equation. Note that phosphorous acid is
a diprotic acid.

$$\ce{H3PO3(aq) + 2KOH (aq) -> 2 H2O(l) + K2HPO3 (aq)} \tag{a}$$

$$\ce{H3PO3(aq) + 2 OH-(aq) -> 2 H2O(l) + HPO3^2-} \tag{b}$$

---

The answers are above. Can somebody explain why it is $\ce{K2HPO3}$ in (a)? I am familiar with monoprotic acid, and this is my first encounter of diprotic acid. Thanks.

Comment: Note that Chemistry SE site policy is using just plain raid for titles, for indexing and searching reasons.

Comment: Instead of writing H_3PO_3 in MathJax, write e.g.  \ce{H3PO3 + 2 KOH -> 2 H2O + K2HPO3}. \ce{} invokes [mhchem](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88)   MathJax extension. It additionally uses expected upright font. See $$\ce{H3PO3 + 2 KOH -> 2 H2O + K2HPO3}$$

Comment: @Poliom. Diprotic acid react always with 2 OH- ions. You should know the first and most important diprotic acid : the sulfuric acid $\ce{H2SO4}$. It reacts according to : $$\ce{H2SO4 + 2 KOH -> K2SO4 + 2 H2O}$$

Comment: I’ll point out that calling it *phosphorous acid* is wrong; it’s *phosphonic acid*.

Answer (score 2):

You have made the assumption that all the hydrogens are attached to oxygens. This is not a good assumption; one of the hydrogens is bonded directly to phosphorus and is not removed by OH-.

A better description of phosphorous acid is HPO(OH)2 with one oxygen doubly bonded to phosphorus  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorous_acid)

Answer (score 1):

Phosphorous acid, or phosphonic acid, is actually far from unique.  You might want to look at what seems to be carbonous acid, $\ce{H2CO2}$.  But it's actually [formic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formic_acid) and its formula is generally rendered as $\ce{HCOOH}$ or even $\ce{H-C(O)-OH}$ -- one hydrogen atom attached to oxygen and the other attached to carbon.  Similarly to the phosphorus compound in the question, even strong bases generally react only with the former hydrogen atom, at least in water solution, so for instance potassium formate is $\ce{KCHO2}$ or $\ce{HCOOK}$.  When you get into organic chemistry you will encounter a lot of compounds like formic acid where some hydrogen atoms can dissociate as protons and others, not.